# UIView subview of another UIView which is subview of UIViewController, not getting centered to UIViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView`( named fwd2) which is added as subview of a `UIView` (named fwd1) and this `UIView` is added as a subview to a `UIViewController(LoginView Controller)`.`And on the click of of proceed button on fwd1 the fwd2 view is opened.And I'm creating Uiview programitically .UIView`(fwd1) is of dynamic height and `UIView`(Fwd2) is of fixed height. Now I want  both the `UIView` (fwd1 & fwd2) center to the `UIViewController`(LoginView Controller). My first `UIView`(fwd1) is getting centered to the `UIViewController` but second `UIView` (fwd2) is not getting centered. I have used

```
fwd1.center = self.view.center;
```

and I have also tried

```
fwd1.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center 
fromView:self.view.superview];
```

I have done same thing with second `UIView` i.e. fwd2 but my second `UIView` i.e. fwd2 is not getting centered to `UIViewController`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to center fwd2 why are you setting center of fwd2?

On a side note:

You might want to use Auto Layout. Using auto layout you can apply constraints like center in container etc.

Here is an Auto Layout Tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: i have followed both the scenarios ... next time I have not set the center of fwd2.. but couln't succeed and result was the same...

Comment: I want this to be done without using AutoLayout....plz help..

Comment: In which function are you writing this code? You might want to try in - viewWillLayoutSubviews. And DO NOT forget to call super's implementation. Also first you need to center fwd1 and then fwd2.
CODE:
fwd1.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superview];

fwd2.center = [fwd1 convertPoint:fwd1.center fromView:fwd1.superview];

Comment: @ Taha, I'm creating fwd2 in proceed button of fwd1. i. e. when I click proceed button of fwd1 then fwd2 is opened. how can I use this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews. plz help me ..

Comment: I have posted the above solution as answer below, please accept it as accepted answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment of thread creator this, solved his problem:

In which function are you writing this code? You might want to try in

`- viewWillLayoutSubviews`

And DO NOT forget to call super's implementation. Also first you need to center fwd1 and then fwd2.

```
fwd1.center = [self.view convertPoint:self.view.center fromView:self.view.superview]; 
fwd2.center = [fwd1 convertPoint:fwd1.center fromView:fwd1.superview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you put the code in the right place?

These code usually should appear in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of UIViewController.

Make `fwd1` centered in UIViewController:

```
fwd1.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
```

Then make `fwd2` centered in `fwd1`, which means `fwd2` should also centered in the UIViewController (They have the same center relative to the UIWindow).

```
fwd2.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(fwd1.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(fwd1.bounds));
```

EDIT:
Thanks to the comment, I correct the code.

Comment: Correction: I think fwd1's bound should be used when setting center of fwd2.

Comment: x coordinate of fwd2 is centered but y co ordinate varies with variable height of fwd1 when I'm using center method only for  fwd1 not for fwd2.

Comment: You should re-calculate the center of `fwd2` to get a new value when you change the height of `fwd1` to keep `fwd2` being in center of `fwd1`. @AdityaYadav

Comment: @ Shuai, I'm creating fwd2 in proceed button of fwd1. i. e. when I click proceed button of fwd1 then fwd2 is opened. how can I use this code in viewWillLayoutSubviews. plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Your fwd2 is subview of fwd1 and fwd1 is the subview of UIViewController. So you need to as below

First make centred align the fwd1 to UIViewController

```
[fwd1 setCenter:[[self view] center]];
```

Then make the fwd2 centred align to fwd1

```
[fwd2 setCenter:[fwd1 center]];
```

Comment: Not necessarily correct. self.view's center is in co-ordinates of UI Window and not self.view. 
Similarly fwd1's center is in coordinates of self.view and not in co-ordinates of fwd1.

Comment: @ Tapas, I had already done this ....but this not giving the solution...the fwd2 is appearing on corner ....